# Trying to use recursion to add words from file in arraylist

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, methods

It has been a while since I have been coding in java and I am now helping a friend who started school. While helping him, I coded an `ArrayList` method to add words from a file and store them within the `ArrayList`. Now that I have made the method, I was trying to think of a recursive way to write the same method.  The current method is as follows:

```
public Lexicon(String filename) throws IOException{
    wordlist = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner scanWord = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    while (scanWord.hasNextLine()){
        wordlist.add(scanWord.nextLine());
        wordCount++;
    }
    scanWord.close();

}
```

Comment: Why do you need a recursion here? it is not clear

Comment: Since you're reading multiple lines from a single file and not multiple files. It does not make any sense to use recursion for this process.

Comment: Blind leading the blind? haha. I don't think you need recursion here at all and using it when you don't need it will definitely wind up confusing either of you if not both.

Comment: If you're looking for a good example of when to use recursion, consider doing a maze solver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why you'd want to do something like this, but I'd assume you just make a method that calls itself until there are no more lines left.

```
public Lexicon(String filename) throws IOException{
....

    public void addWord(Scanner scanWord, List<> wordLst) {
        if (scanWord.hasNextLine()) {
            wordLst.add(scanWord.nextLine());
            addWord(scanWord, wordLst);
        } else {
            // base case - no more words
        }
    }
...
}
```